# vjs_pause function does not exists in swf mode

Tags: video.js

With `video.js 4.0.3`, I got this error when using the flash mode :

> Uncaught exception: TypeError: 'this.el_.vjs_pause' is not a function
>   Error thrown at line 2772

No problem with HTML5 mode.

The pause function seems to be unavailable in the flash object

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same JS error few days back. The fix that worked for me was to first check if the video element or it's parent is visible or not. Only when it's visible, trigger the pause method.

Hope this helps!